# Eclipse "bundle org.eclipse.core.resources is invalid" crash on startup despite moving workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse (Juno running on Windows 7 with java 1.8.0_31) is crashing during the startup with the following error extract being logged (the full log is at http://pastebin.com/g5DS742D)

```
!SESSION 2015-02-20 14:53:09.149 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-20 14:53:39.991
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (1346).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.core.resources is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: trouble in: 
public final class org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin extends org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin:
  public static final String PI_RESOURCES = "org.eclipse.core.resources"
  public static final String PT_BUILDERS = "builders"
  public static final String PT_NATURES = "natures"

  public void stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext) throws java.lang.Exception:
                    ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 409)
                    ALOAD_1     // Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleContext; context
                    INVOKESPECIAL org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.stop (Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleContext;)V
                    GETSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;   (line 410)
                    IFNONNULL L0
                    RETURN   (line 411)
                L0: ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 412)
                    GETFIELD org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspaceRegistration Lorg/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration;
                    INVOKEINTERFACE org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration.unregister ()V
                    INVOKESTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin ()Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin;   (line 414)
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.savePluginPreferences ()V
                    GETSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;   (line 415)
                    ACONST_NULL
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.close (Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V
                    ACONST_NULL   (line 419)
                    PUTSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;
                    ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 420)
                    ACONST_NULL
                    PUTFIELD org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspaceRegistration Lorg/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration;
                    RETURN   (line 421)
  end public void stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext) throws java.lang.Exception

  public void start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext) throws java.lang.Exception:
                    ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 429)
                    ALOAD_1     // Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleContext; context
                    INVOKESPECIAL org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.start (Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleContext;)V
                    NEW org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea   (line 430)
                    DUP
                    INVOKESPECIAL org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init> ()V
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.hasSavedWorkspace ()Z
                    IFNE L0
                    INVOKESTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.constructWorkspace ()V   (line 431)
                L0: INVOKESTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin ()Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin;   (line 433)
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.isDebugging ()Z
                    PUTSTATIC org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.DEBUG Z
                    NEW org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace   (line 436)
                    DUP
                    INVOKESPECIAL org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.<init> ()V
                    PUTSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;
                    GETSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;   (line 437)
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.getRoot ()Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot;
                    INVOKEINTERFACE org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot.getLocation ()Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;
                    INVOKESTATIC org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.PlatformURLResourceConnection.startup (Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;)V
                    ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 438)
                    INVOKESPECIAL org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.initializePreferenceLookupOrder ()V
                    GETSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;   (line 439)
                    ACONST_NULL
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open (Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;
                    ASTORE_2
                    ALOAD_2     // Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus; result   (line 440)
                    INVOKEINTERFACE org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus.isOK ()Z
                    IFNE L1
                    ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 441)
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getLog ()Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/ILog;
                    ALOAD_2     // Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus; result
                    INVOKEINTERFACE org.eclipse.core.runtime.ILog.log (Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;)V
                L1: ALOAD_0     // Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin; this   (line 442)
                    ALOAD_1     // Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleContext; context
                    LDC_W org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace
                    GETSTATIC org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspace Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Workspace;
                    ACONST_NULL
                    INVOKEINTERFACE org.osgi.framework.BundleContext.registerService (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Dictionary;)Lorg/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration;
                    PUTFIELD org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.workspaceRegistration Lorg/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration;
                    RETURN   (line 443)
  end public void start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext) throws java.lang.Exception

  private void initializePreferenceLookupOrder():
                    INVOKESTATIC org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getDefault ()Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/preferences/PreferencesService;   (line 450)
                    ASTORE_1
                    ALOAD_1     // Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/preferences/PreferencesService; service   (line 451)
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getDefaultDefaultLookupOrder ()[Ljava/lang/String;
                    ASTORE_2
                    NEW java.util.ArrayList   (line 452)
                    DUP
                    INVOKESPECIAL java.util.ArrayList.<init> ()V
                    ASTORE_3
                    ALOAD_3     // Ljava/util/List; newOrder   (line 454)
                    LDC_W "project"
                    INVOKEINTERFACE java.util.List.add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
                    POP
                    ALOAD_2     // [Ljava/lang/String; original   (line 455)
                    DUP
                    ASTORE 7
                    ARRAYLENGTH
                    ISTORE 6
                    ICONST_0
                    ISTORE 5
                    GOTO L1
                L0: ALOAD 7
                    ILOAD 5
                    AALOAD
                    ASTORE 4
                    ALOAD_3     // Ljava/util/List; newOrder   (line 456)
                    ALOAD 4     // Ljava/lang/String; entry
                    INVOKEINTERFACE java.util.List.add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
                    POP
                    IINC 5 1   (line 455)
                L1: ILOAD 5
                    ILOAD 6
                    IF_ICMPLT L0
                    ALOAD_1     // Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/preferences/PreferencesService; service   (line 457)
                    ALOAD_3     // Ljava/util/List; newOrder
                    ALOAD_3     // Ljava/util/List; newOrder
                    INVOKEINTERFACE java.util.List.size ()I
                    ANEWARRAY java.lang.String
                    INVOKEINTERFACE java.util.List.toArray ([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
                    CHECKCAST [Ljava.lang.String;
                    INVOKEVIRTUAL org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.setDefaultDefaultLookupOrder ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
                    RETURN   (line 458)
  end private void initializePreferenceLookupOrder()
end public final class org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin

    at org.aspectj.bridge.MessageWriter.handleMessage(MessageWriter.java:47)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor$WeavingAdaptorMessageWriter.handleMessage(WeavingAdaptor.java:737)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor$WeavingAdaptorMessageHolder.handleMessage(WeavingAdaptor.java:682)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1699)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1618)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1379)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1173)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.loadtime.OSGiWeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingService.preProcess(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.adaptors.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook.processClass(WeavingHook.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:165)
    ... 29 more
Root exception:
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java.lang.CharSequence': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:323)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:111)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:461)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:305)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:218)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:97)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:41)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:807)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getSuperclass(BcelObjectType.java:229)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getSuperclass(ReferenceType.java:906)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.addSignaturesUpToFirstDefiningMember(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:95)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.<init>(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:49)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MemberImpl.getJoinPointSignatures(MemberImpl.java:515)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:316)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:202)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ShadowMunger.match(ShadowMunger.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Advice.match(Advice.java:109)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.match(BcelAdvice.java:149)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:3125)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.matchInvokeInstruction(BcelClassWeaver.java:3073)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2774)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2552)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:473)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:99)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1674)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1618)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1379)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1173)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.loadtime.OSGiWeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingService.preProcess(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.adaptors.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook.processClass(WeavingHook.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-20 14:53:40.048
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (1346).
    at
```

The error does look similar to [Eclipse won't start, log error says: ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505187/eclipse-wont-start-log-error-says-objectnotfoundexception-tree-element), [Eclipse error upon start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397914/eclipse-error-upon-start-up) and [eclipse won't start but no error is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847359/eclipse-wont-start-but-no-error-is-shown)

All the solutions mentioned on those Q&A involves either moving to another workspace or cleaning up a corrupted folder on the workspace. I've tried however to change workspace but it did not solve the problem. And since the workspace to which I changed is new, it does not have any of the files and directories described in the other answer as possible corrupted files.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this has happened to me, the error looks the same. In my case I was using Eclipse Indigo, and my system had updated the java version to java openjdk 1.8.0. I solved the problem restoring to the previous java version ( jdk 1.7.0 ). It looks like older Eclipse versions don't work with Java 8

Comment: This should be a comment, and is not an answer. A "Hey, something like this *also* happened to me" is not a true answer to the asker's problem.